# EWS update appointment fails while using impersonation saying that access is denied

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I'm developing an app where I use EWS Managed API to communicate with the EWS. When I try to create an appointment using impersonation (ie, I use a service account X that impersonates a user Y, since I want to create the event in the Y user's calendar) it works well. But when I try to update the event using impersonation like above,  I get the access is denied error. As shown below. I wonder because the same impersonation works fine in creating the appointment.

[image: Exception screenshot]

What's the issue might be?

I searched a lot but couldn't get any right solution.